# AS3: My text file does not want to load into an array as all the others did

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, datagrid, air, text-files

I have 6 txt files with words in them, each on a new line, which gets read and processed into their respective arrays. The code below worked for the first 5 arrays but not the last which is slightly different.

```
var loadFavourites: URLLoader = new URLLoader();;
    var arFavourites = new Array();
    loadFavourites.load(new URLRequest("Lists/Favourites.txt"));
    loadFavourites.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedFavourites);
    function onLoadedFavourites(e6:Event):void {
        arFavourites = e6.target.data.split("\r\n");}
```

I load it in the exact same way but no luck. If I trace arFavourites.length it gives me 0. I just need it to load every 5 values into a datagrid.

```
var iC:int=0;
var iX:int=0; 

while (!iX==arFavourites.length-1)
{
    trace(iX);
    if (iC == 5) {
        dg.addItem({Place: arFavourites[iX-4],Subject:arFavourites[iX-3],Object:arFavourites[iX-2],Feeling:arFavourites[iX-1],Action:arFavourites[iX]});
        iC=0;
    } else {
        iC++;
        trace(iC);
    } 
    iX++;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

Comment: Give the example of 6th file (that doesn't work, link to this file) and one of file that works properly.

Comment: I attempted to use the exact same file to rule out any possibility of the file contents being the problem. The list is formatted like this:
Apple
Pear
Grape
etc.. each on a new line with no spaces

Comment: I understand that this is a silly question, but did ask: Do you call second code snippet from Event.COMPLETE handler after you populate arFavourites array?

Comment: Yes after, so in theory, the array should have been populated..

Comment: Mmmm... 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29 say that this method always return array with length more than 0. So in my opinion reason not in file and reason in some mistake in your program logic. Because I'm not see all code and not see loaded files so I can not answer with something more

Comment: I agree with @kostik . You should try to add an event listener for ioError and to put a trace in the complete event listener to see if it is called. Also, more like a best practice advice, call the "load" method after you call all the "addEventListener" methods you need. It is highly unlikely that it is the cause for your problem but this way the code make more sense

Comment: If you try this code http://pastebin.com/T93M5gz8 with your files - will it trace data from all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing something like this instead:

**Favourites.txt:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

**Code:**

```
var loadFavourites: URLLoader = new URLLoader();;
var favouritesArray = new Array();

loadFavourites.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedFavourites);
loadFavourites.load(new URLRequest("Favourites.txt"));

function onLoadedFavourites(event:Event):void
{
    favouritesArray = event.target.data.split("\r\n");

    for (var i:int = 0; i <= favouritesArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i % 5 == 0)
        {
            trace(i - 4, i - 3, i - 2, i - 1, i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: YOU GENIUS ^_^ it works! Thank you soooooooooo much man!!! If you wouldn't mind could you kindly just explain this "(i != 0 && i % 5 == 0)" quick..

Comment: You're welcome.  The for loop is cycling thru each index of the array.  The Modulus Operator `%`, as in `i % 5 == 0`, is used to know when the index reaches every 5th element.  The condition would also be true at index 0, but we want to ignore that index so we include `i != 0`.  More about the Modulus Operator here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Thank you very much and just for the sake of having a 100% correct answer. There in the trace it needs to start at -5 not -4